# How do we find the value of $x$ where the tangent line to $f(x)$ is horizontal?

Tags: functions, derivatives

Consider the function $f(x)=9x^2 +7x$
The derivative is $f'(x)=18x+7$
The slope of the tangent to the graph of $f(x)$ at $x=2$ is $43$
The equation for the tangent line at $x=2$ is $y=43x-36$

I found all of these answers, but when I get to the last question, I don't know how to solve it. Can anyone tell me how to find it?

The value of $x$ where the tangent line to $f(x)$ is horizontal is $x=?$

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when the tangent line is horizontal, the $y'=0$
then 
$$18x+7=0$$
$$x=-\frac{7}{18}$$

Comment: Thank you! I used $y=43x-36$ instead of $18x+7$, which explains why I couldn't do it.

Comment: @Shiko you are welcome

Answer (score 1):

An horizontal line has a slope equal to zero, so the tangent line at the point of abscissa $x$ is horizontal if and only if $f'(x) = 0$.